# If $A \subseteq B$ then $A \times C \subseteq B \times C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that if $A \subseteq B$ then $A \times C \subseteq B \times C$

I don't even know where to start here, can somebody at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm very new to formal proofs and set theory!

Comment: Pick a point $(a,c) \in A \times C$. Then show that $(a,c) \in B \times C$.

Comment: What does it mean for a point $(a,c)$ to be in $A \times C$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1.  Let $x\in A\times C$ be arbitrary.

Step 2. This means that $x=(u,v)$ where $u\in A$ and $v\in C$.

Step 3. Since $A\subseteq B$, in fact, $u\in B$.

Step 4. Hence $x\in B\times C$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, you are incorrect.  If $C$ is empty, then $A\times C=B\times C=\emptyset$.  The statement is vacuously true, and the proof also holds vacuously.